# Azure Function: How to create dynamic app service plan

Tags: azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

I have an azure function that switches between its dynamic app service plan and elastic plan based on the hours of the day. The issue is, the dynamic app service plan was accidentally deleted.

Is there a way to create a new standalone dynamic app service plan?  I looked at `az functionapp plan create`, it creates every kind of plan except dynamic plan.

I am thinking I have to create a new azure function which will generate a new dynamic plan, then drop the function, which will allow me to use the plan for the original function.

Comment: you could always use ARM/Bicep to create a dynamic app service plan. I think cli has some issue regarding dynamic app service plan

Answer (score 0):

Using the Davidebbo's syntax given in the GitHub Azure PowerShell [docs](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/master/PowerShell/HelperFunctions.ps1), I have created the Consumption (dynamic) hosting plan using PowerShell:

```
$resourceGroupName = "HariTestRG"
$SkuName = "Y1"
$SkuTier = "Dynamic"
$WebAppApiVersion = "2021-02-01"
$location = "centralus"

$fullObject = @{
        location = $location
        sku = @{
            name = $SkuName
            tier = $SkuTier
        }
    }
    
$appServicePlanName = "KrishDynamicAsp01"



New-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/serverfarms -Name $appServicePlanName -IsFullObject -PropertyObject $fullObject -ApiVersion $WebAppApiVersion -Force
```

**Result**:

[image]